# Adding new datasets to a product in Open Data Cube

Tags: open-data-cube

I've created a product and ingested the dataset using standard command line inputs. As expected a new ODC netcdf format dataset is created according to the tiles and location specified. This allows me to remove the 'source_type' product from ODC and original files and only work with the 'output_type', thus freeing up space. However, when I index a new dataset for the same product and ingest the data, no ODC netcdf files are created in the specified location and I have to keep the source files in the current location. It seems the new dataset is being indexed but not ingested. I am using the same script that created the yaml file for the initial ingestion. How do I make sure the new dataset gets ingested?

Comment: By 'source_type' and 'output_type' products are you referring to the index and ingest products respectively?

Comment: Did you have any luck with your question? I bumped into the same problem.